# URP Lit material has a slightly white Background

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, lit, urp

i'm having trouble with a simple Lit URP Material. It always exhibits a slightly white background, no matter what PNG i use. Here is what it look like:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtDeP.png)

As you can see, the background is not completely transparent.

These are the Material settings:

[material settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzvDz.png)

And here's the PNG import settings:

[imoport settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kokyG.png)

Is this expected behaviour? How can i avoid this background issue on a Lit Transparent Material?

Any hint is welcome!

I want to create a Lit Smoke Particle system. It should work with a Lit Material which should have a compleletely Transparent background.